# SAML 2.0 with .Net 1.1

Tags: .net, saml-2.0

Has anyone implemented a SAML 2.0 solution in .Net 1.1, specifically from the Identity Provider's side? One of our vendors is upgrading to SAML 2.0 for SSO and unfortunately we are stuck using .Net 1.1 on our site. I have found many solutions to implement SAML 2.0 using .Net but nothing in .Net 1.1. Any examples would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a budget - Ping Identity ([https://www.pingidentity.com/](https://www.pingidentity.com)) has a couple of options that will work with .NET 1.1.  The integration would be a simple REST API that interacts with a federation service to handle all the SAML or WS-Federation variants out there.

(Disclaimer: I work for Ping)